# remove cookies from browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

how to remove cookies from browser in asp.net c#

Comment: ... and in the future, the first hit on Google for this query will be SO. That's why we need the "small" questions too. :) SO FTW.

Comment: accept the ans if it work for you

Answer (score 22):

Here's how.

```
if (Request.Cookies["MyCookie"] != null)
{
    HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("MyCookie");
    myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
    Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
}
```

Comment: +1, but mention the source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178195(v=VS.90).aspx

Answer (score 8):

Below is code where you can delete all cookies :

```
void Page_Load()
    {
        string[] cookies = Request.Cookies.AllKeys;
        foreach (string cookie in cookies)
        {
            BulletedList1.Items.Add("Deleting " + cookie);
            Response.Cookies[cookie].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
        }
    }
```

for more detail about cookies : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx

Comment: Note that it doesn't make sense to include the BulletedList1 line unless you want to list the deleted cookies as well.

Answer (score 3):

Helper based on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178195.aspx :

```
public static void DeleteCookie(
  HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, string name)
{
  if (request.Cookies[name] == null) return;
  var cookie = new HttpCookie(name) {Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d)};
  response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to delete a cookie is to set its expiration date to a time of the past.
For example,
`Set-Cookie: cookieName=; expires=Wed, 12 May 2010 06:33:04 GMT;`
It works because at the time i'm posting, `Wed, 12 May 2010 06:33:04 GMT` is the http-timestamp, which will never happen again.