# how to remove cookies from browser in asp.net c#, SO answers NOT working

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I'm trying to remove cookies using C# when a user logs out. The code suggestions listed here: [remove cookies from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816452/remove-cookies-from-browser) do not work. I put several of them together in desperation and they are not working.

```
if (Request.Cookies["loginidcookie"] != null)
{
    HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("loginidcookie");
    myCookie.Value = String.Empty;
    myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
    Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
    Response.Cookies.Remove("loginidcookie");
}
Response.Redirect("logout.aspx");
```

So not only am I overwriting the value of the cookie with an empty string, I am setting it to expire yesterday AND removing it from the list of cookies. Yet when I run this code then hit the back button and reload, the cookie is still there with its original value. So how do I get rid of it?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Try this instead:

```
string cookieName = "loginidcookie";
if (Request.Cookies[cookieName ] != null)
{
    var myCookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName);
    myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
    Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
}
Response.Redirect("logout.aspx", false);
```

Note ([from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178195%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)):

> You cannot directly delete a cookie on a user's computer. However, you
>   can direct the user's browser to delete the cookie by setting the
>   cookie's expiration date to a past date. The next time a user makes a
>   request to a page within the domain or path that set the cookie, the
>   browser will determine that the cookie has expired and remove it.

Comment: That's not working. I changed the code as you suggested but the cookie is still there after it was marked as expired. I've reloaded the page several times but the cookie is still there.

Answer (score 3):

You are adding the Cookie and then Removing it from the collection before the response is sent so you are effectively doing nothing.

```
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("loginidcookie");
... and then below
Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
Response.Cookies.Remove("loginidcookie");
```

If you change the cookie to expire yesterday, you need to `leave` the cookie in the collection so that the browser takes care of deleting it once it sees the cookie has been updated with an expiration date in the past. In other words, don't call `Response.Cookies.Remove("loginidcookie");`

Comment: That is not working. I changed the date so that it expired but the cookie is still there when the page reloads. Why not just use the remove cookie command? It seems like it would be the simplist solution.

Comment: You can't remove the cookie. You have to update the existing one. The answer from your duplicate question works. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269715/how-do-cookies-work-in-asp-net/12269912#12269912

Answer (score 0):

Try RedFilter's solution but use Server.Transfer() or Server.TransferRequest() instead of Response.Redirect() which it seems doesn't always let those cookie responses happen due to a possible bug.

Answer (score -1):

Are you checking the cookie after closing the browser? Or reloading the page in the same browser?

If you are opening the page in the same browser you will see the cookie which is expired, but if you opened the new browser and try to access the page again, you would not get the cookie.