# How do Cookies Work in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

The website where I work is made up of several projects (written in several languages). Right now we have to use some awkward code in query strings and session variables to keep a person logged in when they go from project to project. Since cookies are domain specific we're trying to convert to them since they can be set in one project using one language yet be accessed by a different project (on the same domain) using a different language.

However I am having problems changing the value of a cookie and deleting them. Or to be more specific, I'm having trouble having any changes I make to a cookie stick.

For example in my logout code:

```
if (Request.Cookies["thisuserlogin"] != null)
{
    HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("thisuserlogin");
    myCookie.Value = String.Empty;
    myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
    Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
    Response.Cookies.Set(myCookie);
    litTest.Text = myCookie.Expires.ToString() + "<br />" + Request.Cookies["thisuserlogin"].Expires.ToString();
}
```

I wind up with one line being yesterday and the next line being 1/1/0001 12:00:00 even though they SHOULD be the same cookie. So why is it that even though the cookie was set, it's value did not change? Is there a way to force the user's computer to update a cookie's value, including deletion?

Thank you very much.
PS Any URLs you can provide to give an easy-to-understand primer for cookies would be appreciated.

Comment: I edited the title because cookies are not C# specific. ASP.NET is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194(v=vs.100).aspx

```
if (Request.Cookies["thisuserlogin"] != null)
{
    HttpCookie byeCookie = new HttpCookie("thisuserlogin");
    byeCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
    Response.Cookies.Add(byeCookie);

    // Update Client
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
}
```

Comment: I cannot delete all cookies on the domain. I need to delete specific cookies and to have them stay deleted, which as noted in my example, is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) on the client side to capture all of the data going back and forth. This will help you see that your cookie should be set with a date in the past (and missing from the next request too).

As for your textbox output, you're listing the cookie you created expire time and the expire time of the **request** cookie, which doesn't have one. If you were to look at the response cookie instead, you should see the date being set. Also, the call to `Response.Cookies.Set` is unnecessary. `Response.Cookies.Add` should be all you need.

Comment: Fiddler is a great tool for the arsenal

Comment: I don't understand. Because I am using the Add command, shouldn't the two cookies in the output be the same cookie both with a specific expiration date? And if the Set command is unnecessary, why is it there?

Comment: Set is there to maintain compatibility when moving code from ASP to ASP.Net (really VB.Net), just like [Response.End](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end.aspx) (incorrect, see next comment). As for why they don't change, look at it this way. You have one cookie in your Request cookies (that came from the client). You create a brand new cookie with the same name and place it in the Response cookies (that will go to the client). At this point, even though they have the same name, they are two completely different cookies and point to different objects.

Comment: To clarify on the `.Add(HttpCookie)` vs `.Set(HttpCookie)` methods, Add will add a new cookie to the collection and allow duplicates. Set will add it to the collection if it doesn't exist but will update the cookie if it exists. Set does not allow duplicates. See [HttpCookieCollection.Set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookiecollection.set) and [HttpCookieCollection.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookiecollection.add).